# How do I compile numba python code and store it?

Tags: python, numba

I have been using numba to speed up some for loops getting pretty good results. Instead of having code compile just in time (which takes some time) how do I pre compile the code?

here is an example:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
import time.time()

Nk = 5
Nl = 6
Nx = 7
Ny = 8
A = np.random.rand(Nk, Nl, Nx, Ny)

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def Loop( A, X, Y ):
    Nk = A.shape[0]
    Nl = A.shape[1]
    Nx = A.shape[2]
    Ny = A.shape[3]
    for ik in range(Nk):
        for il in range(Nl):
            for ix in range(Nx):
                for iy in range(Ny):
                    Y[ik, il] += A[ik, il, ix, iy]*X[ix,iy]
    return Y

Y = np.zeros([Nk, Nl])
X = np.random.rand(Nx, Ny)
Y = Loop( A, X , Y )
```

What I'd like is to somehow save the compiled function so I don't need to compile it each time.

Comment: a comment after 6 years... `numba` offers [AOT](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.47.0/user/pycc.html) (ahead-of-time compilation) to pre-compile and store it.

Answer (score 1):

In principle you have `pycc`, but as of today (numba 0.17) [the API is not stable](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.17.0/user/pycc.html):

> The API for ahead of time compilation isn’t stabilized. Adventurous users can still try the `pycc` utility which is installed as part of Numba.

However a skilled reader can extract some information [from the source itself](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/0.17.0/numba/pycc/__init__.py).

Answer (score -1):

Ahead-of-Time compilation (AOT) maybe too heavy for this purpose(I don't need to compile it each time). Just use @jit(cache=True) is sufficient.